How to navigate a VPN and internet from two different connection at the same time on Linux
I have a Windows laptop with a VPN software to access a private network, I also have a Linux laptop from which I would like to use the VPN.
So I plugged my phone to the Windows laptop and I turned on the usb tethering on the phone to reach the internet from windows, and I enabled the wifi hotspot in windows to share the connection, then I configured the windows VPN connection to be shared on the wifi hotspot, but when I connect from linux to the wifi hotspot exposed by windows I can only reach the private network, no internet from linux (both the internet connection and the vpn work from windows).
So I turned on the bluetooth hotspot on the phone and I connected to it from my linux machine. Now I can reach the internet but not the private network.
To recap the phone is the bluetooth and usb hotspot, windows is connected to the phone through usb, linux is connected to both the phone via bluetooth and the Windows laptop via wifi.
             windows <-----+
              | usb        |
              v            |
internet <- phone          | wifi
              ^            |
              | bluetooth  |
             linux --------+

(the arrows indicate which is connected to which)
What should I configure to reach the internet and the vpn network from my beloved Linux machine (with gnome)?

The vpn client should be adding routes to tell the windows PC which traffic to send through the vpn (try route print in windows cmd to see them). You basically need to add the same routes on the linux machine (with route add) to tell it to send vpn-network traffic via the wifi interface. It requires some knowledge of routing/networking though, since you can pretty easily lose all network access with a bad route
